# line 47, in schemachange raise ValueError("Invalid root folder: %s" % rootfolder) ValueError: Invalid root folder: /home/vsts/work/1/s/migrations

Tags: azure-devops, valueerror, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
This is my Yaml code

# Deploy database changes using snowchange
# https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/snowchange
# (see https://aka.ms/yaml for the YAML schema reference)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - /migrations
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
variables:
- group: demo-variables
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.8.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.8.x'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Starting bash task'
      echo "PROJECT_FOLDER $(PROJECT_FOLDER)"
      python --version
      echo 'Step 1: Installing schemachange'
      pip install schemachange --upgrade
      echo 'Step 2: Running schemachange'
      schemachange -f $(PROJECT_FOLDER)/migrations -a $(SF_ACCOUNT) -u $(SF_USERNAME) -r $(SF_ROLE) -w $(SF_WAREHOUSE) -d $(SF_DATABASE) -c $(SF_DATABASE).SCHEMACHANGE.CHANGE_HISTORY --create-change-history-table
  env:
    SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $(SF_PASSWORD)
```

After this run- getting below output result:

File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.11/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schemachange/cli.py", line 47, in schemachange
raise ValueError("Invalid root folder: %s" % root_folder)
ValueError: Invalid root folder: /home/vsts/work/1/s/migrations
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Bash

Comment: Can anybody know what causing this error

Comment: The error is obviously from Python -- look at the path and name of the file mentioned by the error message. This has nothing to do with pipelines. We know nothing about the logic of that Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `$(Build.SourceDirectory)` where you have `ProjectFolder/migration` or the name of your own folder path, and remove the `x` behind Python and use Python 3.8 or lower.

Comment: Given that none of these references exist in the OP's original code, it would be much more useful if you aligned your answer with the paths and properties they're referencing, or offer an answer with more contextual code. As is, someone unfamiliar with the syntax is likely to be confused by what you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

For the above yml code if the migrations folder and azure_pipeline.yml file reside in same branch then (PROJECT_FOLDER) value which is set to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) in demo-variables will work.
If your migrations folder and azure_pipeline.yml file reside in different locations then
Option 1: PROJECT_FOLDER value has to be set to the correct path so that your schemachange command could recognize the root folder i.e.., migrations.
Option 2:Include a checkout step and checkout to the migrations folder branch(Ex:- checkout: git://SampleProject@Dev_Branch) then
(PROJECT_FOLDER) value which is set to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) will work in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).