# I have used the Bash script task in Azure DevOps for Snowflake schema change and using the Microsoft ubuntu agent

Tags: bash, azure-devops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have used the Bash script task in Azure DevOps for Snowflake schema change and using the Microsoft ubuntu agent. Now I need to change the agent to a Windows agent. Can you please help me with the below code to change? So that it will run smoothly on the windows agent also.

### **Code**

```
echo 'Starting bash task'
      echo "PROJECT_FOLDER $(PROJECT_FOLDER)"
      python --version
      echo 'Step 1: Installing schemachange'
      pip install schemachange --upgrade
      echo 'Step 2: Running schemachange'
      schemachange -f $(PROJECT_FOLDER) -a $(SF_ACCOUNT) -u $(SF_USERNAME) -r $(SF_ROLE) -w $(SF_WAREHOUSE) -d $(SF_DATABASE) -c $(SF_DATABASE).SCHEMACHANGE.CHANGE_HISTORY --create-change-history-table
  env:
    SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $(SF_PASSWORD)
```

---

When I run the same code with the windows agent, the build is failing with an error as an invalid root folder. The above is working fine with the ubuntu agent.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?
You can also use the Bash task on 'Microsoft-hosted Windows agents' and it will handle it correctly(according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/cross-platform-scripting?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#consider-bash-or-pwsh)

I am not sure if there is anything to change in your code

Comment: When i run the same code with the windows agent build is failing with an error as an invalid root folder. The above is working fine with the ubuntu agent.

Comment: Maybe it can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543153/line-47-in-schemachange-raise-valueerrorinvalid-root-folder-s-rootfolder

Comment: Hi Sri, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I took the liberty of editing your question to include your description of the error, which you put in your comment above. After all, the error information is essential for anybody hoping to help you fix the problem. Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70307396/edit) your question to make it clearer if necessary, more than once if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the agent doesn't have bash, you could just make it a Powershell task.

```
          - task: Powershell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host 'Starting Powershell task'
                Write-Host "PROJECT_FOLDER $(PROJECT_FOLDER)"
                python --version
                Write-Host 'Step 1: Installing schemachange'
                pip install schemachange --upgrade
                Write-Host 'Step 2: Running schemachange'
                schemachange -f $(PROJECT_FOLDER) -a $(SF_ACCOUNT) -u $(SF_USERNAME) -r $(SF_ROLE) -w $(SF_WAREHOUSE) -d $(SF_DATABASE) -c $(SF_DATABASE).SCHEMACHANGE.CHANGE_HISTORY --create-change-history-table -v
            env:
              SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: $(SF_PASSWORD)
```